# Eclipse: Export as runnabe Jar overwrites manifest

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

For Java 7 I have to update my runnable jar (for web start) so the manifest have to include the permissions tag. So I created a `META-INF` folder under `/src` and put my `MANIFEST.MF` file in there. Exporting the project with `Export -> Runnable JAR` just overwrites my manifest with the useless default one ...

Next step was to use the `Export -> JAR` where no external libraries were included (like the opencmis libraries from apache) no matter which options I used. This jar can not work.

Last step was to let the build.xml be created from the first step and I added the manifest tags in the build.xml by hand and run the ant build. This was working, but now in the `META-INF` folder of the Jar I have 5 `LICENSE` files, 5 `NOTICE` files and 5 `DEPENDENCIES` files. I am not able to sign this jar because all those files have the same name.

**To make it clear**, I want:

- include custom MANIFEST.MF
- Extract required libraries into generated JAR to inflate the referenced jar files and copy the classes into the generated jar

With eclipse export wizzards, there is **no way to achieve BOTH behaviors**!

So can anybody tell me how I can add the permissions tag into the manifest, build a `Runnable JAR` with all needed libraries and sign the jar?

Thank you all!
Michael

Comment: @aaron-digulla that answer is from 2010 and is no longer valid.

Comment: @sventechie: Seems like you can't do it anymore with Eclipse. Use the command line with Ant or Maven.

Answer (score 0):

When exporting, you can flag "use existing manifest".

Comment: Using Eclipse Kepler and Luna, I dont have the option to 'Use existing manifest' with the 'Runnable JAR Export Wizzard'. This option is only available in the 'JAR Export Wizzard' where I dont can include external libraries like the apache opencmis libs.

Comment: References to external libraries/JAR files must be specified in the manifest file. Then they will be reasonable included.

Comment: And how can I tell the exporter to extract libraries so only the needed class files are in the JAR? with the library jars my Jar is about 9mb big, with extracted library class files only 1mb. And why in gods sake cant the 'Runnable Jar Export Wizzard' use my custom manifest and overwrites it? That just dont makes sense?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm

Comment: Do you see any step/option where I can choose my own manifest file? Sorry but I am frustrated why things are alyways have to be so complicated :/

Comment: I understand your frustration, but I am actually doing it with my environment just by following the guide. What about attempting a command line export? On which OS are you working?

Comment: I mean, steps 2 and 3 of this guide is what I am doing: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-runnable-jar.htm

Comment: I am on Windows 7. Yes exporting my project as a runnable jar is no problem, the problem is that I can not use this jar as web start application because it requires the permissions tag in the manifest (since Java 7). But I have not found an easy way to do this yet.